# geometric transformations in 3d - combining rotation and scaling

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

A graphics programmer wishes to draw objects that have been stretched in a particular direction.
They know how to stretch an object along the X or Y axes, but they need help to stretch the
object in an arbitrary direction.

Here are two figures that they provided to help explain what they
mean by stretching an object. Figure B-1 shows (a) the original object, which is a circle of radius 1,
(b) the circle stretched by a factor of two along the X axis, (c) the original circle stretched by a factor
of 2 along the Y axis, and (d) the original circle stretched by a factor of 2 in a 45 degree direction.
Figure B-2 shows (a) an original unit square and (b) the result of stretching it by a factor of 2 in a 45
degree direction. Note that stretching is about the origin of the axes, not the centre of the object
being stretched

[image]

B1. What well-known transformation corresponds to (, 0) – i.e. stretching in the X
axis direction by a factor of s? Your answer should include the parameters of the
transformation, and will include at least one mathematical expression that depends on s.

St(s,0) corresponds to scaling in the x-axis by a factor of s.

B2. Use the “classic way” to derive a sequence of well known elementary
transformations that are equivalent to (, ). Write the transformations using the
abbreviated notation presented in lectures.

Rotate(),Scale(s,1)

B3. Expand each of the elementary transformations in your solution of question B2 to
homogeneous matrices. The elements of each matrix will be mathematical expressions
involving  and/or .

()
\begin{bmatrix} &−  &\\ & &\\&&\end{bmatrix}

(,)
\begin{bmatrix}&&\\&&\\&&\end{bmatrix}

B4. Multiply the homogeneous matrices together to obtain the combined
transformation as a single matrix containing mathematical expressions.
\begin{bmatrix}  &−  &\\ &  &\\&&\end{bmatrix}

B5. Prove that (1, ) is the identity transformation for all values of .

B6. (−1, ) is clearly not an identity transformation. Intuitively, what is it? It may
help to sketch the result of transforming the unit square B-2(a), or the flag A-1, for some
simple values of . Mathematically, it may help to consider your answers to questions B1
and B2.

B7. Apply (2,45) to the four points of the unit square. Show whether the labels on
the points in figure B-2(b) are correct or not.

B5 and beyond is where I need help. I dont understand how St(1,) is the identity. Wouldnt that just rotate the object by ? Im afraid I mightve done B1-B4 wrong, so if someone could comment on that Id really appreciate it.

Comment: Your answer for B2 is wrong, which cascades through the rest of the problem set. Hint: the illustrations of stretched circles are misleading.

Comment: @amd ive been trying to figure out how its wrong, but I cant see. can please you explain which is misleading and how?

Comment: The pictures of the transformed circles make it look like you scale and then rotate, but that produces the wrong transformation. You end up with a “stretch” of the wrong amount in two different directions, neither of which is the desired, as you can see by computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the resulting matrix. I’m not sure what they mean by the “classic way,” but one way to get the correct result by finding a basis in which the transformation matrix is diagonal and then applying a change of basis to it. There’s a basis for which this is two rotations.